# Immediate Save Dialogue to Download HTML5 Canvas Image - Not Saving on Server

Tags: html5-canvas, savefiledialog

I am working on a purely JS/HTML page where the user can upload an image and the image is converted to canvas data and displayed.  Then the user can click on a button to have alterations performed to the pixel data, changing the display.

Now, if the user wants to save the image they can right click and do a save as and they are prompted to save the image as canvas.png; I would prefer, however, to just have a button "download image" that the user can click to pop up the standard save dialogue box.

My question is how can make such a button, that pulls the canvas data into a standard image download prompt?

Here are some more details:

If you do a "view image" on the displayed image the url it goes to is like this:
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA (lots more stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob Seidelin, has created a library that allows you to save the canvas as an image. You can find his [site here](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)!